# why would a daemon configure a port, then the port is not usable?

Tags: services

Ubuntu 12.04 on an AMD64 Fujitsu industrial PC. Ports are on Shentek PCI cards, the "manager" daemon insmods the xr17v35x driver (using the system call with the command in a buffer), then starts the other processes (also daemons) that use the ports (also using the system call with "/etc/init.d/ start&" in a buffer). These in turn read their config data out of files, open the ports (eg /dev/ttyXR4) then configure the ports using a string read from the config file and passed to stty (again via system with the command and config data in a buffer).

I have seen similar on Debian: I configure a port, then something else (unknown to me) clobbers the port with the wrong baud rate. On that job, I had the luxury of a device which sent back replies to my messages, so if it stopped working or the data coming back looked garbled I could run my Initialise() function again. This avoided the problem.

On this job, I don't have that luxury, all we can tell is from human observation that the devices I send messages to are not doing what they should. I have a TestRig, which is able to inject a PROCESS_RESET message into the relevant daemon, when I do so, it runs the Initialise() function again and normal operation is achieved.

So either I'm going the wrong way about setting things up, or I need to find what's clobbering the port settings, and disable it.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: who's ranting? I'm trying to describe the symptoms and the conditions under which they appear. The ports, btw, are 4 off RS232 on one PCI card, the others are 2 off RS485, on another PCI card. I have a suspicion, but can't prove it, that either the xr17v35x driver or some other Linux component takes its own decision on initialising the ports on the cards the driver finds, which happens at some stage after I have tried to do so from my own code. Another way of putting the question is: Is there anyone with experience in this scenario who can enlighten me?

Comment: It is impossible to tell from what you posted. Your question is tl;dr , somewhat of a rant, and simply states you are having a problem. Could be anything from misconfigured server to network problems to a firewall on the client or server. You should update your question to include server configuration, error messages, and what you have done to debug the problem. Start on the server and try to connect to local host and then move to the client.